# Need help : restoring a netgear dgn1000 v3 adsl modem/router

Tags: firmware, hardware

coming in from openwrt forum: https://forum.openwrt.org/t/trying-to-rescue-bricked-dgn1000-v3-need-help/36909

currently have serial console but i may have borked the u-boot looking for help on how to jtag or spi flash the chip to restore original firmware on the modem

Currently on the serial console i get this output

```
ROM VER: 1.2.0                                                                  

CFG 04                                                                          

EEPROM Data OK                                                                  

UART
```

running binwalk gives:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
192           0xC0            Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:lzma, size: 3548940 bytes, 1283 inodes, blocksize: 131072 bytes, created: 2015-04-07 07:20:16
3551424       0x3630C0        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 5398000 bytes
```

extracting gives: 
[image: extracted files image]

here's the serial output logs before i bricked the device at the end you can see the upload got interrupted and bricked the device
 https://pastebin.com/SQUsq1Zv

need help/ideas/pointers on how to reflash the original firmware.
thanks.

Comment: as per openwrt forum helpers 
i need to find

   `Lantiq UART loader script

    U-boot compiled to run from RAM

    U-boot compiled to install in flash
`